# Continuity of limit function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am a little bit lost and not sure if I have understood everything correctly. Maybe you can give me feedback on my subsequent proof.

The question is:

Let $c$ be the space of convergent sequences equipped with the norm $\Vert(x_k)\Vert_\infty = \sup \{\,\vert x_k\vert, k \in \mathbb{N}\,\}$.

Show that the function $\lim\colon c \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, that maps $(x_k) \mapsto \lim_{k \to\infty} x_k$ is not only continuous but also Lipschitz-continuous.

---

My proof:

Be $(x_k) \in c$ and $(x_{kn})$ a convergent sequence of elements of $c$ with the the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(x_{kn})= (a_k )$. So there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ for a given $\delta >0$ so that for all $n>n_0$: $\Vert(x_{kn})-(a_k)\Vert_\infty = \sup\{\,\vert x_{kn}-a_k\vert, k \in \mathbb{N}\,\} < \delta$.

Let for an $\epsilon >0$ be: $\vert \lim(x_{kn})- \lim(a_k)\vert=\vert\lim_{k \to \infty}x_{kn}- \lim_{k \to \infty}a_k\vert < \epsilon$. As $(x_{kn})$ is convergent for all $n$ and $(a_k)$ is a convergent sequence I can write: $\vert \lim_{k \to \infty}(x_{kn} -a_k )\vert<\epsilon$. 
Then we conclude for all $n>n_0$: $\vert\lim_{k \to \infty}(x_{kn} -a_k)\vert \leq \sup \{\,\vert x_{kn}-a_k\vert, k \in \mathbb{N}\,\} = \Vert(x_{kn})-(a_k)\Vert_\infty < \delta$.

If we set $\delta := \epsilon$, it yields a $\delta$ which fulfils the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-criteria for continuity. With $L = 1$, the function $\lim\colon c \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is also Lipschitz-continuous.
$\Box$

Is this correct? Or do you have any suggestions?

best regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not quite understand your proof. But the fact itself is easy to understand: the limits of two convergent sequences cannot differ by more than the maximum distance between the sequences. I would argue by contradiction: suppose $\lim x_k=l$, $\lim y_k=m$. If $|l-m|>\sup |x_k-y_k|$ we would have $|x_n-y_n|>\sup |x_k-y_k|$ for large $n$ (since $x_k-y_k\to l-m$), and this contradicts the definition of $\sup$.

Comment: good point, but how would you do it with the $\epsilon-\delta$-criteria? I mean how would you set your $\delta$ w.r.t. $\epsilon$ so that for an arbitrary but fixed $(a_k) \in c$ it follows that for every Element $(x_k) \in c$ with $\Vert (x_k)- (a_k) \Vert_{\infty} <\delta$ we have $\vert lim(x_k)-lim(a_k)\vert <\epsilon$ ?

Comment: What the proof by contradiction shows is that $|l-m|\le \sup|x_k-y_k|$ that is if you want the left hand side to be less than $\epsilon$ it is enough to choose the right hand side less than $\epsilon$ in other words $\epsilon=\delta$ and then your mapping is Lipschitz with constant $L=1$.